# Why are there plastic bags at the back of seats on Copenhagen local trains?

Tags: trains, copenhagen

While travelling on the local Copenhagen train system, I was curious to find plastic bags at the back of each seat.

[image: Plastic bags on Oresundstag]

Why are these kept there / what purpose are they supposed to be used for?

Comment: Trash.  It is the typical way of doing it in all Danish trains (except the S-tog).  There are also actual trash cans in the lobbies around the doors.

Comment: For those who get train sick.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Firstly, that's not a local train - it's the international train that links Denmark and Sweden.

To answer your question: I asked about this when I was travelling on the Øresundståg a couple of years ago as I wanted somewhere to put trash. The train manager told me I can use it for "whatever I want" and that the bags are there as a convenience for customers and to help reduce the amount of trash left openly on the train.

Comment: The same trains operate local services between Elsinore, Copenhagen and the airport (only some of which continue towards Sweden).

Comment: Didn't know this was the international train! I was going to Humblaek. Also the weird thing is there ARE bins on the train near carriage exits, so I'd have expected littering to be less of an issue.

Comment: Even with bins, people sadly love to leave their rubbish wherever is most convenient for them.

Comment: It *is* a local train by designation as opposed to long-distance or high-speed trains such as the X2000. Apart from the cross-border Malmö–Kopenhagen bit, they perform regional train duties far into Sweden with a significant number of passengers (if not the overwhelming majority) *not* crossing any border. Also, bahn.de gives the train numbers a preceding *R* for *regional* i.e. local.

Comment: Yep, nothing stops local trains from crossing a border (thus becoming "international"). I can think of at least two hands full of such trains in Europe.

Comment: @neo Trains are pretty big. How many of them can you fit in two of your hands? :-D

Comment: Øresundståg are regional trains around Øresund (the strait north of Copenhagen/Malmø).  The area just happens to be in two countries.

Comment: @MJeffryes: Unfortunately, some of those people would find it inconvenient to pull the bag from its hook.  Much easier to just open your hand and let gravity do the rest.

Answer (score 2):

As stated these are international trains and I think the route in Sweden is much longer than the route in Denmark. [Öresundtåg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%98resundst%C3%A5g) is owned by 6 Swedish regions and the Danish DSB.

All intercity and some local trains in Sweden have plastic bags by the seats. They are usually located under the windows (pictured below). Most Danish intercity trains also have a very similar solution (see comments).

[image: The Polynova plastic bags in use by Swedish public transportation]

They are easy to remove allowing the staff to easily clean the train.

However, Öresundståg has a different solution with bags on the back of the seats. I'm not sure why but it could be that the supplier of these bags is Danish.

Comment: Domestic intercity trains in Denmark do too, though typically "under the windows" rather than "by the seats".

Comment: @HenningMakholm using the same bags as pictured in the answer?

Comment: x @Mikael: Not _exactly_ those bags, but a comparable size and material. (You're supposed to take the bag with you, and deposit it and your trash in a garbage can on the platform).

Comment: I've sent an e-mail to Öresundståg with a link to the question. Hopefully we'll get an official response.